# Return response during multi if in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

I'm doing a [unit testing](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/testing/), I'm checking fields in two databases collections so  during it I have to do a multi if conditions like this:

```
for doc1,doc2 in itertools.izip(docs1, docs2):
    if ... :
        if ... :
            response = 'Error'
        else:
            response = 'OK'
    else... :
        if ... :
            response = 'Error'
        else:
            response = 'OK'
    if ... :
        if ... :
            response = 'Error'
        else ... :
            response = 'OK'
    else ... :
        if ... :
            response = 'Error'
        else ... :
            response = 'OK'
```

so I want to assert a response if the error happened in one of this ifs, to give an answer like this:
 `self.assert400(response, message="Bad request, empty body.")`

and when the whole process is okay to give an Ok response.

All I want is to avoid writing this:

```
     if ... :
            if ... :
                self.assert400(response, message="Bad request, empty body.")
            else:
                self.assert200(response, message="OK.")
     else... : 
            if ... :
                self.assert400(response, message="Bad request, empty body.")
            else:
                self.assert200(response, message="OK.")
```

So what to achieve this?

I thought to create an if condition in the end of it but that wouldn't stop the for loop?Please help me?

Comment: Can you not just have an if-check depending on the value of `response` and then use `break` to exit the for-loop if you need to?

Comment: I have a really hard time understanding what you want to achieve. Is the code you're showing the unit test or the code you want to test ?

Comment: @Jylo I edited my question, can you check it? That code is the code on unit testing method.

Comment: @Jokab Can you give a simple example of it?

Comment: Generally speaking, if you have a unit test you should really only be testing for one particular case. If you have different error conditions, you would write two unit tests.  However, for this particular case it looks like you may be able to use a default value and then just test each error individually.

Comment: It sounds like you have real, working code that you want to make better. Consider positing to codereview.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: @L-Jones9 yes I will do that, maybe like that is better to clarify things, but again for one test case I have 4 cases, 2 of those if they are executed an error is generated, and two of them are ok  so, in the end, one message should appear.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should consider using a default value and only checking for the error case:

```
response = "OK" # default value

for doc1,doc2 in itertools.izip(docs1, docs2):
    if ... :
        if ... :
            response = "Error"
    else... :
        if ... :
            response = "Error"

    if response == "Error":
        break

# If no errors were found, then the result must be OK
if response == "Error":
    self.assert400(response, message="Bad request, empty body.")
else:
    self.assert200(response, message="OK.")
```

This achieves that only one error is enough to make the whole thing fail. I am a bit unclear on what you actually want to do, so do comment if this is not what you expected.

Comment: thank you for your code, but this gives an OK message everytime that loop is okay, and in case of the whole code is okay I want to type only one time an okay message.

Comment: @EstinaEsitna So if I understand you correctly: if you find one error, print error and exit loop. If no errors are raised, that is, every response was OK, then print OK once?

Comment: Yes that's true, but if the loop is executed 100 times, I have 100 ok printed on the code,  I want to print it only one time in case if the result is okay?

Comment: @EstinaEsitna Did this answer help you? If so, consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you're not really unit-testing. The structure in your function and unit test are exactly the same. So if your code change the test will have to change too. I don't think that testing the "=" operator is worth your time.

I could be wrong but I think you should have a function taking doc1 and doc2 and returning a response. Then you unit test the return value for specific imput value. Something like this :

```
result = foo(doc1,doc2)
self.assert_equal(result.message, "Bad request, empty body.")
result = foo(doc3,doc4)
self.assert_equal(result.message, "OK.")
```

In general, making your code "unit-testable" makes it better.